# MonoRepo - Create React App - Jest 26.6.0 - Error "a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, monorepo, lerna

My mono-repo looks like:

- React App (CRA) => Brings in jest 26.6.0 ( it is not included as the dependency as CRA just brings it in)
- package1 => Brings in jest 27.4.5 (Included as dependency)

When I run the build, it complains that "a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree".

Ofcourse if I add "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" to the `.env` file in the project, it bypasses this issue. But I'd like to not do that.

Tech-stack:

- Mono-repo
- Typescript
- Lerna
- CRA
- Typescript packages

Any tips?